# In EmberJS, how do you update the URL in a dynamic route when a model changes?

Tags: url, dynamic, ember.js, routes, ember-data

Due to our URL scheme, we have a route with a dynamic segment that acts like a file path:

```
@resource 'node', { path: '/*node_path' }, ->
```

If a user changes the name of one of the nodes in the path, how do you get the URL to automatically update to reflect this? We're using ember-data.

I've tried adding an observer to the models from the controller, but it throws an error because the models change during the route transition period.

```
folderNameUpdated: (->
  console.log 'Folder name changed'
  Ember.run.next @, ->
    @send 'invalidateModel'
).observes('model.name')
```

Comment: So you want to change url after property change? Seems like you are talking about `query params` in my opinion here. See  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/

Comment: Whoops, I should have been more clear: the model is updated by a server-side event with WebSockets, not direct user input on the page.